# Can this 'if' statement be removed?

Tags: scala

I use this code to read file into memory :

```
val lines = Source.fromFile(fileToRead, "utf-8").getLines
```

To iterate over some of the lines I use :

```
lines.take(linesToReadFromDataFile).foreach(line => {
```

Sometimes I may want to iterate all lines :

```
lines.foreach(line => {
```

To determines if to real all of the lines I could use a boolean 'useAlllines' and do something like :

```
if(useAllLines)
   lines.foreach(line => {
else
    lines.take(linesToReadFromDataFile).foreach(line => {
```

Using Scala is there a better way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this will be enough:

```
val toIterate =
  if(useAllLines)
    lines
  else
    lines.take(linesToReadFromDataFile)

for ( line <- toIterate ) {
  ...
}
```

You could also combine `useAllLines` and `linesToReadFromDataFile` in a single variable of type `Option[Int]`:

```
val toIterate = optionLinesToReadFromDataFile.map{ lines.take(_) }.getOrElse(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines.take(if (useAllLines) lines.length else linesToReadFromDataFile).foreach(
```